# How to put specific value to multiple subqueries?

Tags: mysql

I have to make a query in which I need to find department name and the max ratio of average salary of female to male.

I completed the query which gives me the exact ratio, but I have to put hardcoded value to dept_no column and I want to modify it show that I it can fetch the value from department table at all the position.

```
select dept_name,
    ((select  max(avg_val) from 
        (select avg(s.salary)as avg_val 
         from salaries s, employees e, dept_emp dp 
         where  e.emp_no = s.emp_no 
            and dp.dept_no = 'd005'
            and e.gender = 'F'
            and e.emp_no = dp.emp_no
        group by s.emp_no,e.emp_no,dp.emp_no,dp.dept_no
        ) tmp
    )  
 /
    (select  max(avg_val) 
     from ( select avg(s.salary) as avg_val 
            from  salaries s, employees e, dept_emp dp 
            where e.emp_no = s.emp_no 
            and dp.dept_no = 'd005'
            and e.gender = 'M'
            and e.emp_no = dp.emp_no
            group by s.emp_no,e.emp_no,dp.emp_no,dp.dept_no
          ) tmp
    )
) as Avgerage 
from departments 
where dept_no = 'd005';
```

Present Result:

```
dept_name      Average
'Development', '0.96394531'
```

Required result:

```
all department name and their average ratio.
```

Comment: @PaulSpiegel most likely you are right , topicstarter can better read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. So we don't have to guess annymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL:

```
select dept_no, dept_name, B.sal / C.sal as Avgerage
from departments A
join (select  dp.dept_no, max(avg_val) as sal from
        (select dp.dept_no, avg(s.salary)as avg_val
         from salaries s, employees e, dept_emp dp
         where  e.emp_no = s.emp_no
            and e.gender = 'F'
            and e.emp_no = dp.emp_no
        group by s.emp_no,e.emp_no,dp.emp_no,dp.dept_no
        ) tmp
  GROUP BY tmp.dept_no
    ) B ON A.dept_no = B.dept_no
join (select  dp.dept_no, max(avg_val) as sal from
          ( select dp.dept_no, avg(s.salary) as avg_val
            from  salaries s, employees e, dept_emp dp
            where e.emp_no = s.emp_no
            and e.gender = 'M'
            and e.emp_no = dp.emp_no
            group by s.emp_no,e.emp_no,dp.emp_no,dp.dept_no
          ) tmp
      GROUP BY tmp.dept_no
    ) C ON A.dept_no = B.dept_no
GROUP BY dept_no,dept_name;
```

I don't have the SQL DDL so there might be some amendments required but the main Idea is to group by all the salary values by departments separately for males and females and then calculate the average in the master query also grouping by the department number.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As you say I have to do some modification but now it is working fine thanks a lot for your help.